# I made salsa and washed jars but did not put in boiling water ? They all sealed? Is this safe

Tags: canning

I made salsa and after all done realized I did not sterilize the jars? Is this safe or how can I fix?

Comment: Hi and welcome - I'd suggest that you check out the related answers here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35785/first-time-canning-forgot-to-sterilize-my-jar-advice-please?rq=1 It would also help us provide good answers if you can post details of your recipe - whether you're working from a tested, known-safe method is a big factor in canning. Have you made this before? Did you process the jars in a boiling-water bath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jars of salsa, do I have to boil the jars if they sealed on their own?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40097/jars-of-salsa-do-i-have-to-boil-the-jars-if-they-sealed-on-their-own)

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer:**

It's a gamble. I would reseal the jars. Just remove the lids, and do the full boil and seal process. Nothing is lost.

**Reason:**

As mentioned in a similar [post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40098/69108), you really need to do the full boil process to ensure all the contents, including the salsa, are safe for storage.

One reason for that is, if you even breathe on the jars, bacteria and microorganisms could have landed inside. The full boil will sterilize all of that.

Happy jarring!